# INNER JOIN and SORTING issue in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

This is kinda hard to explain, therefore I'm gonna do this step by step

I have created a table called list_names, there I store the list of names such as (George, Tina, Bobby, etc...)

I have also created another table which called names_items, this table is basically where I store how many items this person has, it looks something like this:

```
id | name | Item
1  | Tina | Bag
2  | Tina | Pencil
3  | Bob  | TV
4  | Bob  | Computer
```

My goal is, to display all the names from list_names then count the sum of the items of each person has from names_items and join them together. if the person haven't bought anything yet, return 0. I also want to sort the result by the sum of the items of this person bought. Is there anyway to accomplish this using mysql only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should do it;

```sql
SELECT names.name, COUNT(item) AS items
FROM names
LEFT JOIN names_items 
  ON names.name = names_items.name
GROUP BY names.name
ORDER BY COUNT(item) DESC
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80460/7).

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just use a left join between `names` and `names_items`.

```
SELECT names_items.name COUNT(item) AS itemcount
FROM names
LEFT JOIN names_items ON names.name = names_items.name
GROUP BY names_items.name
ORDER BY itemcount DESC
```

If a name has no items, the respective item will be `NULL` and `COUNT(item)` will return `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  list_names.name,
  names_items.item,
  COUNT(names_items.name) AS `Count Per Person` 
FROM
  list_names 
  INNER JOIN names_items 
    ON (list_names.id = names_items.id) 
GROUP BY names_items.name
```